# JS: setInterval and clearIntervals with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm probably tired for staring at this for too long,
maybe someone can clear this up for me:

```
//scripts in whispers are setup this way.
var something = function(){
    setInterval(function1,1000);
    setInterval(function2,1000);
    blah .. blah...
}

//function2 is the same as this one
var function1 = function(){
   ajax to do something on server
   blah...
   blah...
}

//button to stop things from running anymore
$('.stop').live('click',function(){
  clearInterval(function1);
  clearInterval(function2);
  return false;
}
```

I should be able to stop function1 and/or 2 from running after
clicking the button yeah? For some reason - the ajax calls within the
two functions keep running and pinging the server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`clearInterval` does not take a function as a parameter, it takes an ID returned by `setInterval`.

```
var theID = setInterval(something,1000);

clearInterval(theID);
```

Comment: Thanks James!

Thanks to JesseB's example as well (below): http://stackoverflow.com/q/8251941/294895

Answer (score 1):

James Montagne is right, but I figured I'd code it up using what you've provided:

```
// declaring this as a closure, so 
// that your timers are kept out of the global namespace
(function (){
    var timer1,
        timer2;

    // declaring 'something' this way makes it private
    // use this.something if you want to be able to access this publicly
    var something = function(){
        timer1 = setInterval(function1, 1000);
        timer2 = setInterval(function2, 1000);
        // blah .. blah...
    }

    //function2 is the same as this one
    var function1 = function(){
        // ajax to do something on server
        // blah...
        // blah...
    }

    // button to stop things from running anymore
    $('.stop').on('click', function(e) {
        // kill out our timers
        clearInterval(timer1);
        clearInterval(timer2);

        // prevent the browsers default click action
        if (e.preventDefault) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
        return false;
    }
}())
```

Answer (score 0):

As James Montagne has answered above, `clearInterval` takes the id returned by the `setInterval` function. Please this [example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setInterval#Example) at mozilla developer network.

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to post the link as a comment instead of repeating an answer?

Answer (score 0):

James Montagne's answer is correct. However, if you don't want to store the ID returned by `setInterval`, you can use [jQuery timers](http://jquery.offput.ca/every/) plugin

```
$(window).everyTime(1000, "task1", function1);    //set interval
$(window).stopTime("task1");                      //clear interval
```